# How to declare items directly in a list in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a `Dummy` object in QML:

```
import QtQuicks 2.7
Item { property int foo: 0 }
```

And another abject needs to create a list of instances of such an object.  But how do I declare it ? Using straight QML declarations in the list does not work :

```
import QtQuicks 2.7

Item {
    property var fools: [
        Dummy {foo: 1},
        Dummy {foo: 2},
        Dummy {foo: 3}
    ]
}
```

I get the error `Cannot assign multiple values to a singular property`

How to properly declare a list of dummies ?

Comment: Is QtQuick 2.7 the highest version you can use, or can you use the latest?

Comment: Can't you use [ObjectModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-objectmodel.html) or [VisualItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-visualitemmodel.html) (depending on your version of QtQuick)?

Comment: Do you get an error? What do you expect?

Comment: The error is: `Cannot assign multiple values to a singular property`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a recent Qt version (tested with Qt 5.9, I don't know when it was introduced, but not in 5.7) you can use the type:

```
property list<Item> itemList: [
    Item {},
    Item {},
    ...
]
```